# how to remove specific case elements from 1 string in python

Tags: python, string, list, url, compare

here i have a string with a website html data it's stored in urldata

````
urldata = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(urllib.request.Request(url, headers=headers), timeout=3).read(),features="html.parser")```
````

when i print `urldata` it's showing the html data from the specific page
so here i need to remove the https and http links

so i can fillter the http or https links by this way

```
web_page = str(urldata)
urls = re.findall('http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA- F]))+', web_page)
print(urls)
```

so here i'm thinking to remove the http&https links from "urldata"

I have the url list already in that url variable (type "list")

so is there any way to compare the list "urls" with "web_page" string

and remove the urls from web_page string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) to substitute each url with an empty string:**

```
web_page = str(urldata)
web_page = re.sub('http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA- F]))+', '', web_page)
print(web_page)
```

---

---

UPDATE:

```
web_page = str(urldata)
for url in urls:
    web_page = web_page.replace(url, '')
print(web_page)
```

Comment: Or `web_page = web_page.replace(url, '')`?

Comment: But your `re.sub()` based solution looks even shorter.

Comment: @AnnZen it's not updating actually when i print web_page it's same output,  
actually the web_page is "one" string (whole html code from web) into 1 string, urls is a list ,so it's contains around 40 urls  , so here we are trying to remove one by one urls from that "web-page" string, i think is that will update with any forloop conditions ? can any one help me.?

Comment: @VishalVijayan Updated.